# Grab only the latest comment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a typical User - Post - Comment model in Rails, every user can create a Post and also can create Comment, question is how to grab every user latest comment on specific post.

```
Example:

Post A have 3 user making comment
User 1 have comment 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
User 2 have comment 1, 2, 3, 4
User 3 have comment 1, 2
```

So the view I want is just the latest comment for every user:

```
Post A have 3 user making comment
User 1 latest comment that is 6
User 2 latest comment that is 4
user 3 latest comment that is 2
```

How to do it ?

thanks

Comment: So when Post A has 3 users, are you saying that the Post model has_many users, or that it has_many comments which, in turn, belong_to a user?

Comment: User has many post and comment, Post has many comment and belong to user, Comment belong to post and belong to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
post.comments.for_user(current_user).last
```

add a named_scope in your model

```
class Comment 
    named_scope :for_user, lambda{ |user| {:conditions=>{:user_id => user.id}}
end
```

That should do the trick.

If you rather do it in rails,

```
messages_by_users  = post.messages.group_by(&:user)

messages_by_users.each do  |key, value|   
    messages_by_users[key] = value.last
end
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a one-query way to get this job done, if you want to display the latest comment for all 3 users...

Comment: Matchu, I added a rails solution to load the query only once - by loading all comments into memory), I wonder if there are  other better ways using SQL

Comment: @ez, the first solution only grab current_user latest comment, how to grab the other one ?

Comment: for the first solution, you will need to have a list of the users, users.each do | user| post.comments ... end. for the second solution, you don't need to loop through all users.

Comment: @ez, many many thanks I like your second solution but I just use the value.last for every iteration in view.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to get this kind of data and usually I end up doing two queries. In my case I have Blogs and their Posts and I wanted a list of the 3 most recent blog posts with the restriction that the blogs are unique, I dont want 2 posts from the same blog. I ended up doing something like this (MySQL):

```
q = <<-EOQ
SELECT id,pub_date FROM
  (
  SELECT id,blog_id,pub_date
  FROM posts 
  ORDER BY pub_date DESC 
  LIMIT 40
  )
t
GROUP BY blog_id
ORDER BY pub_date DESC
LIMIT #{num_posts}
EOQ
post_ids = Post.connection.select_values(q)
Post.find(:all, :include => [:blog], :conditions => ["id IN (?)", post_ids], :order => "posts.pub_date DESC")
```

So in your case you might have something like:

```
q = <<-EOQ
SELECT id FROM
  (
  SELECT id,post_id
  FROM comments 
  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 40
  )
t
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
EOQ
post_ids = Post.connection.select_values(q)
Post.find(:all, :include => [:blog], :conditions => ["id IN (?)", post_ids], :order => "posts.id DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database is assigning sequential IDs to the comments, you can do this:

```
class Comment
  named_scope :most_recent, lambda {
     lastest_comments = Comment.maximum :id, :group => "user_id, post_id"
     { :conditions => [ "comment_id in ?", lastest_comments.map(&:last) ] }
  }
end
```

This gives you a two-query method that you can use in a variety of ways.  The `named_scope` above pulls back the most recent comments for all users on all posts.  This might be a problem if your database is gigantic, but you can certainly add conditions to make it more specific.

As it stands, it is a flexible method that allows you to do the following:

```
Comment.most_recent.find_by_user @user   #-> the most recent comments on all posts by a user
@user.comments.most_recent               #-> same as above

Comment.most_recent.find_by_post @post   #-> the most recent comments on a single post by all users
@post.comments.most_recent               #-> same as above

Comment.most_recent.find_by_user_and_post @user, @post    #-> the specific most recent comment by a certain user on a certain post
@post.comments.most_recent.find_by_user @user             #-> you get the idea
```